# custom [super init] (subclassing)

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, subclass

Given the following classes:

*MCAchievementCenter:MCModel* (subclass)

```
-(id) initWithDelgate:(id<MCAchievementNotifications>)delegate {

    self = [super initWithRessource:@"achievements"];
    if (self)
    {
        self.delegate = delegate;
    }

    return self;
}
```

*MCModel* (superclass)

```
-(instancetype)initWithRessource:(NSString *)ressource {

    NSString* ressourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ressource
                                                              ofType:@"json"];
    NSData* raw = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:ressourcePath];
    return [super initWithJSONData:raw];
}
```

**Note**: `-initWithJSONData:raw` is a category method on `NSObject` that populates the object with json data. (see https://github.com/uacaps/NSObject-ObjectMap)

**My Problem**: The initialization of `MCAchievementCenter` fails as it becomes `nil`.

Am I doing something wrong? 
Any help appreciated.

**Update**: app enters loop >

[image]

[image]

Comment: `-initWithJSONData:raw` is working. Example: `[[MCUser alloc]
            initWithRessource:@"user"];` is returning expected results.

Comment: Use a ***debugger***, set breakpoints and inspect the variables. Is ressourcePath == nil? Is raw == nil? What does `[super initWithJSONData:raw]` return? What does `[super initWithRessource:@"achievements"]` return ? Etc ...

Comment: Your screenshot shows only that `[[MCAchievementCenter alloc] initWith...]` returns nil. - You have figure out *why* it returns nil. As I said: Step through your code and inspect the variables. Compare them with what you expect.

Comment: @MartinR You should be setting `self` within the `init` methods; see the end of this article: http://blog.wilshipley.com/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `initWithJSONData:raw:`? Although, I have to note, initializer as a method implemented in a category - is not something conventional

Comment: @trojanfoe: As I understand it, that matters only if your init method does anything with `self` after calling `[super init]`, which is not the case here. But I may be wrong ...

Comment: @SashaZats this category is provided by the https://github.com/uacaps/NSObject-ObjectMap repo/pod. As mentioned in the first comment the method procedure - populating the object with data - itself is working properly.

Comment: @MartinR Agreed; however it's a pattern that should be encouraged.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Agreed! - But anyway, unless OP provides more information what exactly fails during the init process we can only guess about the problem.

Comment: Also, have you tried tracing `self.achievmentCenter` - sometimes compiler optimizes values out so you see them as `nil` in debugger while the variable is present. Besides, have you checked the data that you're getting prior to `initWithJSONData`

Comment: 1) NSData *raw is valid- otherwise the json parser throws an exception.

Comment: @CodeMound: That is not correct. I tried it with  "NSObject+ObjectMap", and `[super initWithJSONData:raw]` returns `nil` if the JSON data is invalid. - Btw. it should be `[self initWithJSONData:raw]`, but that probably does not make a difference.

Comment: I double-checked it now: the json data itself is valid

Comment: Ok; I've found the issue: Apparently the MCModel:initWithRessource constructor runs in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Two things

1. [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:ressourcePath] in **MCModel** is nil or not.
2. [super initWithJSONData:raw] in **the category you had created** returns nil or not.

It might happen that resource is not available at that path , and then when you call super initWithJSONData , that too returns nil as *raw* data is nil.